# Hide and restore the GUI Mutiple forms in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have multiple form application. Form 1 is Login form for user validation. Form1 goes to Form2(Menu form). Form 2 leads to Form3 which is only popupform and hides the form2 when it is open.Form 3 goes to Form 4. Now from Form4 ,with button click, I need to restore the Form2 without creating a new instance. I tried using singelton approach, getting error.Code as follows as described above.

Form1:

```
private void click_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{      
   if ((user.Text == username) && (pswd.Text == password))       
   {
      Form2 menu = new Form2();
      menu.Username = user.Text;
      //hides the form1
      this.Hide();      
      menu.ShowDialog();
   }
}
```

Form2:

```
private static Form2 instance;

public static Form2 Instance
{
   get
   {
      if (instance == null)
      {
         instance = new Form2();
      }
      return instance;
   }
}

private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   //Hide the form2
   Hide();
   //Bring up your PopUp form
   using (Form3 form3 = new Form3())
   form3.ShowDialog();         
}
```

Form3:

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)   
{
   Hide();
   Form4 form4 = new Form4();
   form4.Show();
}
```

Form4:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Form2 form2 = Form2.Instance;//error occured as Mainmenu does not contain a reference for Instance and no extension method accepting a first argument of type 'Mainmenu'
}
```

Basically, I want to restore the Form2 that was hided.Any help would be appreciated!Thanks

Answer (score 1):

How about keeping track of the Forms parents so you have direct access.
For example in your Form1:

```
menu.Parent = this;
Hide();
menu.ShowDialog();
```

Then in your Form2 when Form3 is called:

```
using (Form3 f3 = new Form3())
{
    Hide();
    f3.Parent = this.Parent;
    f3.ShowDialog();
}
```

Then when you want to dispose of Form3:

```
this.Parent.Show();
this.Parent.Focus();
this.Dispose();
```

Something along this lines for as many open forms as you need. If you need to drop back to the previous form, then make the Parent 'this' instead of 'this.Parent'

Comment: It worked  well for my application. Managing multiple forms is bit tricky as my application tends to grow bigger. I'll implement the way you suggested in handling multiple forms.Thanks !

Comment: You could also declare all the Forms as global variables, but without knowing the details of your project it's hard to tell what the best method of handling them is. Are you possibly trying to implement too many forms when the approach could be simplified? Just things to think on. Hope it all goes well!

Comment: I am new to c# programming.   I am creating  user interface application on controlling the lights in  a building(smart control) by fetching lights from server and controlling it. I am extensively using forms and now having difficulty in managing them.Could be please give suggestion on how it can be improved to manage them. If possible,please provide me with example code .

Comment: What forms are you currently using? Think of how you want it laid out for user accessibility. Would a Tab control be helpful? Do you actually need as many forms as you are using or is a popup dialog enough for questions? If you want to compress your files you currently have and post a link, I'll take a look at them for you.

Comment: Create an MDI application and hide the mdi parent however creating variables for each form and calling them as needed